# BackgroundWorker Crashes application when doWork called

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, crash

Here's some code:

```
class myclass
{
  enum STAT
  {
    IDLE=0;
    READING,
    WRITING,
    PAINTING,
    SKATTING
  }

  public STAT status = STAT.IDLE;
}

void reading()
{//code}

void writting()
{}
...
//Rest function bodies form accordingly

Button_click()
{
  myclass test = new myclass();

  status = STAT.READING
  bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

  while(status == STAT.READING)
  {
     label.text = "READING";
     progressbar.value++;
  }

  status = STAT.WRITTING;
  bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

  while(status == STAT.WRITTING)
  {
     label.text = "READING";
     progressbar.value++;
  }
 ..........
}

 bgWorker_doWork()
 {
   switch(status)
   {
     case STAT.READING:  test.reading; break;
     ......
   }

   status = STAT.IDLE;
 }
```

My code is similar to the above but when i click the button thw whole app crashes with no excepsions or anything. can someone please help? i cant figure out what im doing wrong.. :)

thank you and happy new year everyone.

Comment: Shouldn't  status = STAT.READING be test.status = STAT.READING?

Comment: Describe "crashing" better. Do you have a debugger attached?

Comment: @Henk the application runs. i see the form. i click the button and the form dissapears. Nothing relative runs in task manager.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i dont know if it helps anyone but i solved my problem using some Thread.Sleep(100) statements before starting each function inside DoWork(). It seems that the execution flow was too fast so the while(status == ...) loops always evaluated to false. I just had to give each function some time to work before checking the STATE.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Backgroundworker completely wrong.

It is intended to offload work from the main-thread. You are doing that but then you tie up the main thread completely in the 2 `while(status == ...)` loops. That part is blocking and maybe crashing your app.

Read up on the [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx) and use the Completed and ProgressChanged events to manage the UI.

Also note the `e.Error` property in Completed.

Also, I would rather use 2 separate Bgw's for Reading and Writing. This status stuff is overcomplicated.

Comment: i understand what you mean. i tried utilizing 2 bgworkers in the following way: everything that takes place in button_click() is transfered in the bgworker1.dowork(). Button_click() now starts bgworker1. now in bgWorker1.dowork() starts bgWorker2 and bgWorker2.dowork() contains the switch(). I have the exact same result. Even if i make a single bgworker and make new threads in its dowork(). ill try using seperate bgworkers for eatch action read,write etc.. thank you.

Comment: No, you just have to get rid of those while loops. Don't move them around.

Answer (score 0):

The variable test is local to Button_click(). You might want to declare it on the class level.

Comment: there must be a test var somewhere around otherwise it wouldn't compile. Maybe NOT declaring test in button_click is the solution...brave though you tried to answer, I didn't know where to start...

Comment: Exactly what I ment: NOT declare it in button_click, but instead declare it on the class level.

Comment: my test variable is now declared in class level. nothing changes. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, in `test.reading()` are you accessing any UI controls? If so, that's the source of your crashing problem.